# Disabling GameObjects in a scene reduces build size in Unity, how?

Tags: android, unity-game-engine

I know I am probably going to be called "troll", but did you know that disabling GameObjects in a scene in Unity reduces build size in Unity?

We have discovered this accidentally while developing our new game (for Android). I was checking some models and forgot to enable GameObjects in the scene and hit "Build", resulting in a ~50MB APK, which was ~60MB prior to this. I have re-enabled them and had another build which again gave me a ~50MB APK.

These are the steps that I followed:

- Create a new scene.
- Add various GameObjects to your scene (I used actual 3D models with textures).
- Build it.
- Observe the build size.
- Go back to your scene.
- Disable your GameObjects.
- Write a script to enable them on Awake.
- Build it.
- Observe that the build size is considerably small even though nothing has changed.

Can anyone confirm this? Also, can anyone explain this? How is this even possible?

Edit: On request:

- Unity 4.5.2
- All objects have mesh filters, mesh renderers and various colliders.
- All objects are batching and lightmap static, some are navigation static.
- The scene is lightmapped.

Comment: Interesting question. Of the top of my head, may be it's related to the light map of the scene?

Comment: Are your objects static? Does it work with empty game objects? Are they required to have renderers, mesh filter components and materials with textures for this effect to be observed?

Comment: Also, what exactly Unity version are you using (just in case)?

Comment: However downvoted this question, I would _really_ like to know the reason, because the quality of this question is much higher than usual for [unity3d] tag.

Comment: @golergka yes, the scene is lightmapped, but how can this be related? I mean, does Unity include lightmap twice when the objects are enabled, but only once if they are disabled? Something strange is going on, and I can't understand.

Comment: I think that during export Unity runs lightmapping only on enabled objects. Do your objects look lightmapped when they are disabled during build?

Comment: @golergka yes they do.